# Jaspererports iReport: split report into several excel sheets on export

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have a report which I created using iReport designer. The report contains 3 datasets and 3 tables, which get filled with data from those datasets. Each table is located in detail band. Our business owner wants these 3 tables to be displayed on 3 different excel sheets upon excel export. I have checked several tutorials and posts, but none of them seems to work for me. Help needed! Thanks in advance!

Comment: add pagebreak after each table, then set property net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet  to true
 for more reference visit http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/533232/how-create-multi-worksheet-excel-jasper-repor

Comment: Thanks. Everything I needed was there )))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `pagebreak` after each table, then set property

`net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet` to `true`

like this

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet" value="true"/>
```

for more reference visit [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/533232/how-create-multi-worksheet-excel-jasper-repor) page

Comment: Everything you said, and also in report properties setting net.sf.jasperreports.page.break.no.pagination=apply was the final step after which it worked